# If there a free way to bypass Elementor Pro for restricting user roles to "Access to edit content only"?

Tags: wordpress, free, elementor

I searched online a lot for finding a free alternative for Elementor Pro role manager. I would like to restrict my clients for editing whole pages in Elementor and restrict them to "edit content only", an option available in Elementor Pro. I couldn't find any plugin or any code to do this. I just started beginning my own company so I don't want to invest in Elementor Pro at this stage. Anyone has the golden advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to restrict access to Elementor, you could try the plugin [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/).

After installing the plugin you can go to Members > Roles and then choose which one you want to edit.

Then you should see the Elementor tab, click it to see the permission types you can manage.

Hope it helps.